# Feedly is based on what ajax framework?

Tags: ajax, firefox, plugins, firefox-addon

Feedly.com is kind of cool. Can you guys give me some clues about it is developed based on what ajax framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask about the Firefox plugin its based on their own framework, you can download the freedly.xpi, change its extension to .zip and open it to see what is inside.